# Fastest way to find nearest coordinates

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have a sqlite database with list places, I want to find nearest place to the given coordinates.

At first I tried:

```
var closest = _dbContext.Places.GroupBy(x => Math.Pow((latitude - x.Latitude.Value), 2) + Math.Pow((longitude - x.Longitude.Value), 2))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
            .Take(take).ToList();
```

But I got an error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Place>()
    .Where(m => m.Latitude.HasValue && m.Longitude.HasValue)
    .GroupBy(
        keySelector: m => Math.Pow(
            x: __latitude_0 - m.Latitude.Value, 
            y: 2) + Math.Pow(
            x: __longitude_1 - m.Longitude.Value, 
            y: 2), 
        elementSelector: m => m)' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Math.Pow' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information.
Translation of method 'System.Math.Pow' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

So in order to bypass this error I inserted Where & AsEnumerable which fixed the problem but it is extremely slow due to.

```
public List<Place> GetNearestPlace(double latitude, double longitude, int take)
{
    var closest = _dbContext.Places.Where(x => x.Latitude.HasValue && x.Longitude.HasValue).AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => Math.Pow((latitude - x.Latitude.Value), 2) + Math.Pow((longitude - x.Longitude.Value), 2))
                .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                .Take(take).ToList();
    
    IEnumerable<Place> tmp = closest.SelectMany(group => group);
    List<Place> newList = smths.ToList();

    return newList;
}
```

I am looking for a solution that can retrieve the data as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replicate and speed up your approach, since you are only squaring the values you may multiply the scalar values by themselves to achieve this eg.

```
var closest = _dbContext.Places
                        .OrderBy(x => (
        (latitude - x.Latitude.Value) * (latitude - x.Latitude.Value)
                                      ) + 
                                      (
        (longitude - x.Longitude.Value) * (longitude - x.Longitude.Value)
                                      )
                        )
                        
                        .Take(take)
                        .ToList();
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I still get this error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side.'

Comment: I've updated the proposed answer and removed the group by, the above now pushes the ordering into the orderBy. It will take me some time to replicate your setup and perform a full test, however until then. Let me know if this works for you.